# AWS sending logs from cloudwatch to elasticsearch but there is one less in elasticsearch without any errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-elasticsearch

It is hard to explain so I will elaborate here.

So I am getting logs to cloudwatch and I've set a trigger that send it to elasticsearch.

It had been working fine until now, all logs in cloudwatch going to elasticsearch.

Here are two logs, one that went into elasticsearch (first line) and one that did not (second line). Cloudwatch didn't output any error message. I am guessing it might be because mapping is different therefore it is not showing up in kibana but they same exactly same format, also I can see same format as 2nd line but different time in kibana.

```
543.21.6.235 (65.345.48.17) - - [15/Nov/2019:06:02:00 +0900] "GET /c1/support/list?time=2019-11-1406%3A36%3A14 HTTP/1.1” 200 1794 “-” “http/3.12.1"
552.11.3.781 (155.883.38.813) - - [15/Nov/2019:06:02:00 +0900] "GET /c1/support/list?time=2019-11-1505%3A36%3A51 HTTP/1.1" 200 1255 "-" "singsing/5 Network/67.1 Erdin/11.0.0"
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong, I don't think it is mapping error now however maybe something to do with AWS itself.

When I run query in elasticsearch and in kibana with same time range it outputs same number of data which means it is not due to mapping error.

Comment: Have you tried to search with a full-text query (in Dev Tools) instead of using the Discover view?

Comment: @Val yes just did. Seems it renders same number of hits.

Comment: And I suppose you're using the managed AWS ES service, right? Also have you [set this up](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/big-data/viewing-amazon-elasticsearch-service-error-logs/)?

Comment: @Val Yes I am using AWS and yes I have but no outputs.

Comment: The logs stream to elasticsearch via lambda function ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html if it does, you can check the logs under the lambda cloudwatch log group